# Ruby I/O Existence Issues

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I have a decent amount of knowledge about Ruby code, but I do have an issue with my current project. I use Gosu to make 2D games (and once I figure out how, simple 3D games), so I need a resolution.

And this is where my question comes in, why does Ruby keep giving me an error when seeing if the settings file exists? I've been trying to get it working with the file not existing, which keeps giving me the error, "'initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ./settings.set (Errno::ENOENT)" which has been annoying me for the last few days. The file gives no issues and actually works as intended when I leave the file created, but I want it to be where if the file gets deleted off of someone's computer, it rebuilds the file and creates a new one using default values.

Here's the area that it keeps crashing at:

```
settings = []

settings_file_existance = File.file?("settings.set")

if settings_file_existance == true

  File.open("settings.set").readlines.each do |line|
    settings.push line
  end

else

  settings_file = File.open("settings.set")
  settings_file.write "800"
  settings_file.write "\n" 
  settings_file.write "600"
  settings_file.close

end
```

I have tried looking for fixes on this site, along with many others, but no one so far has been able to help.

Comment: Whats the actual line number/code you get the error on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
settings = []

if File.file?("settings.set")
  settings = File.read("settings.set").split("\n")
else
  File.open("settings.set", "w") do |file|
    file.write "800\n600"
  end
end
```

---

As a side note, consider that the above code will set `settings` only if *settings.set* file exits, otherwise it will remain in an empty array (i.e. `[]`).

If you wish to avoid that, just define settings with the default values, for example:

```
settings = [800, 600]
```

Now if *settings.set* file doesn't exist, then `settings` will be `[800, 600]`, otherwise it will be overwritten with the values from *settings.set*.

To avoid writing `800` and `600` twice, you could use `settings` variable to get the values to be written in the new file, for example:

```
file.write(settings.join("\n"))
```

Putting it all together, your code would look like this:

```
settings = [800, 600]

if File.file?("settings.set")
  settings = File.read("settings.set").split("\n")
else
  File.open("settings.set", "w") do |file|
    file.write(settings.join("\n"))
  end
end
```

Comment: Ugh... That didn't fix the problem... I just love the File I/O in Ruby...

Comment: The same one, "No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - settings.set (Errno::ENOENT)"

Comment: @RucksackGamer Are you passing the `"w"` option?

Comment: I just did. It said that "w" wasn't a recognized as a variable. This is how I set it up if that matters (if File.file?("settings.set",w))...

Comment: @RucksackGamer You must use quotes or double quotes since `w` is a string; like this: `("settings.set", "w")`

Comment: Oh geeze, I forgot that... Thank you, I got the file somewhat working. Now I just need to figure out which access mode is what I need for it to work right. Again thank you, I've been stumped on that for about 3 days now.

Comment: @RucksackGamer Glad to help. Also check updated answer for a side note regarding how you set `settings` value. And don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking the tick on the left) if my answer helped solve your issue. :)

Comment: @RucksackGamer [Check here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) for available access modes.

Comment: It definitely did.